# Android Studio Button color & border

Tags: android, android-studio, border, calculator, textcolor

The buttons are fine. But when I set a new background color for every button. The border of every button disappears. The lines between the buttons disappears. How can I bring back the borders? or the lines around the buttons. btw im using relative layout.

This is the xml code:

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#191919"
tools:context="com.example.meds.calculatorapp.CalcActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="/"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#00FA9A" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#00FA9A"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="*"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#00FA9A" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="7"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#00FA9A" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="9"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="8"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:text="="
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#00FA9A" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button8"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#808080" />
```

[image: Sample Output]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an Android Tag to your question.

And when you replace the background of an Android Button it also replace the border.

So if you want a background AND a border on your button, you need a background drawable WITH borders on it. You can use 9patch images to do that cleanly.

Another way (less clean) is to not touch your button background (if you want to keep the current borders) and to change the color of the layout behind your button.

Comment: Added the `adroid` tag. Should be fine now!

Comment: what 9patch image?

Comment: Images that can be extended, used generally for borders http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to check, my money is ont he color. It is possible that the background color of your buttons is the same as teh color of the lines, and thus, you don't see them.